# Adding Namespace to header in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

As per my initial requirement, I have written xslt code to remove namespace prefix from the code , but the namespace is also getting removed.

Below is the input file , output file and xslt code.

input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:nfeProc xmlns:ns0="http://www.p.in.br/nf" versao="4.00">
<ns0:cUF>35</ns0:cUF>
<ns0:cNF>10131445</ns0:cNF>
</ns0:nfeProc>
```

transform.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nfeProc versao="4.00">
<cUF>35</cUF>
<cNF>10131445</cNF>
</nfeProc>
```

I also want to append n0 as namespace prefix for just nfeProc element and two namespaces inside it. Below is the desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<n0:nfeProc xmlns="http://www.p.in.br/nf" xmlns:n0="http://www.p.in.br/nf" versao="4.00">
<cUF>35</cUF>
<cNF>10131445</cNF>
</n0:nfeProc>
```

Please let me know what changes are required. Kindly help

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. If you add the default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.p.in.br/nf"` to the root element, then the descendant elements will inherit that namespace - so the output will be semantically identical to the input.

Comment: Requirement is I want to remove ns0 prefix from all elements and for nfeProc i want to change it to n0 and add namespace but the descendant elements should be without namespace prefix neither ns0 nor n0

Comment: That would be a purely cosmetic adjustment. Why would you need to do this?

Comment: I know Michael, can you please let me know how can we achieve it? it will be great help.

Comment: No. It's a lot of work for no good reason, AFAICT. And depending on your specific processor, it might not be even possible to get the exact result you want.

Comment: I got it to work using Saxon 9.8 HE (See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ3915) but this uses XSLT 2.0 functionality. But, in any case, if you are sending the XML to an application, and that application needs the XML in this format, then it is this target application that needs to change, not the one producing the XML in the first place....

Comment: Hi Tim.. I'm not sending the xml to any application . I am writing this output xml in a file.

Comment: Tim, desired output is n0 as namespace prefix not ns0

Comment: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ3915/1 if you really wanted to do this, but it really doesn't make a difference what prefix you use (or whether there is a prefix at all). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an XSLT 1.0 option, but like others have said, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense and may not work with all processors...

**XML Input**

```
<ns0:nfeProc xmlns:ns0="http://www.p.in.br/nf" versao="4.00">
<ns0:cUF>35</ns0:cUF>
<ns0:cNF>10131445</ns0:cNF>
</ns0:nfeProc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:n0="http://www.p.in.br/nf" xmlns="http://www.p.in.br/nf">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <n0:nfeProc>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>           
        </n0:nfeProc>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<n0:nfeProc versao="4.00" xmlns:n0="http://www.p.in.br/nf" xmlns="http://www.p.in.br/nf">
<cUF>35</cUF>
<cNF>10131445</cNF>
</n0:nfeProc>
```

Fiddle (thanks @tim-c): http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NJ3915/3